# How to receive a single packet larger than my buffer?

Tags: c#, .net

A trivial synchronous example of receiving a message from a remote server might look like this (based on MS docs for `Socket.Receive()`:

```
// Displays sending with a connected socket
// using the overload that takes a buffer, offset, message size, and socket flags.
public static int SendReceiveTest4(Socket server)
{
    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
    try 
    {
        // Blocks until send returns.
        int byteCount = server.Send(msg, 0, msg.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes.", byteCount);

        // Get reply from the server.
        byteCount = server.Receive(bytes, 0, server.Available, 
                                   SocketFlags.None);

        if (byteCount > 0)
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Error code: {1}.", e.Message, e.ErrorCode);
        return (e.ErrorCode);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What if the other party sends me 300 bytes as the 'answer'? Should I loop calls to `Socket.Receive()` with a buffer 256 bytes until it is exhausted? But how do I know when to *stop* looping? If I loop one to many times, it will block forever waiting for a response that isn't coming.

I know async options exist but they don't fundamentally resolve the problem, they just hide it.

Comment: Use Asynchronous method.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: You don't usually pass `server.Available` but bufferSize as size. You then loop over the receive until you receive less than buffer size (or even 0). Of course, you'd want to accumulate the buffer contents from each iteration.

Comment: Sometimes the examples can really be misleading (to say the least). Don't blindly copy their code. It is really often not production-ready.

Comment: It doesn't really need an option to "allocate as needed" -- a buffer of, say, 8K would be enough to receive anything but a jumbo frame, and for the case of jumbo frames you don't really want the framework to "allocate as needed", due to the perf impact. TCP is stream-based and not message-based; receiving X bytes when your actual message is Y is always possible and must always be accounted for in code, regardless of your buffer size (and note that X need not even have a relationship with packet size, as the kernel is free to reassemble stuff as well).

Comment: Note that the framework does offer plenty of high-level alternatives to `Socket` with fewer pitfalls -- while the MSDN is replete with samples for `Socket` (many of dubious quality), not that much code actually has a need for using sockets directly as opposed to things like `TcpClient`,  `NetworkStream` and the newly minted `System.IO.Pipelines` (not to mention things like `WebClient`, `WebSocket` and WCF). Do consider any of those in preference to tackling low-level socket code directly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert they don't seem to ever recommend which to use when; most questions I see here seem to use the lower-level too, as well as examples I see online.

Comment: My contention is that the vast majority of that material is misguided, reinvents the wheel in many ways (often poorly and with no regard for performance despite being low-level), and the attention given to the topic is the direct result precisely of the relative complexity of accessing TCP streams directly using `Socket` (especially if you roll into it with an incorrect model of how TCP actually works, as most newcomers do, which is no shame). To a first approximation, use `TcpClient` for clients and `TcpListener` for servers (with `async` methods), operating on `NetworkStream`s.

Comment: If you want to get a taste of the kind of problems you run into with network code that has to perform really well, take a look at the problems solved by [`System.IO.Pipelines`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/), and note how even there they're using `NetworkStream` rather than `Socket` directly (although the basic issues of parsing messages that are not prefixed by a length remain the same).

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for that, very helpful. I should add that I will be talking to 3rd-party software which I've no idea how it works - presumably all these higher-level options are for my benefit as a coder and are raw TCP under the hood i.e. the other end doesn't matter? I have follow-up Q's but comments aren't the place, partly as you might guess about TCP itself

Comment: I clarified a more answerable question